# Why does gregoriancalendar.get() require these numbers within them?

Tags: java

I have got some code from a friend which prints the current date and time and I dont understand some of the code, can someone explain it please?

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class lab
{
 public static void main(final String[] array) {
     final GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
     final int value = gregorianCalendar.get(5);
     final int value2 = gregorianCalendar.get(2);
     final int value3 = gregorianCalendar.get(1);
     final int value4 = gregorianCalendar.get(13);
     final int value5 = gregorianCalendar.get(12);
     final int value6 = gregorianCalendar.get(10);
     System.out.println("Current date is  " + value + "/" + (value2 + 1) + "/" + value3);
     System.out.println("Current time is  " + value6 + " : " + value5 + " : " + value4);
 }
}
```

I dont understand why for all the gregoriancalendar.get functions have the respective numbers in them? I have changed numbers to see what they cause and am getting random results, so I don't get what they mean.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the outdated Calendar API anyway. Use `java.time` package instead.

Comment: What about reading the documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: @Kayaman how would i implement that? i just began learning java.

Comment: @JainamShah then start with the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and you don't need to guess things and trust "code from a friend", and you'll get up to date info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are constants, defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SECOND). Use that for reverse lookup. Usually you don't use the integer values but the constant names.

The `get(5)` means `get(DAY_OF_MONTH)`, `get(2)` means `get(MONTH)`. The constants are far more readable, I have no idea why somebody would write the code the way you received it. Possibly it was decompiled.

I strongly advise against using the old `java.util.Calendar` api, please use java8+'s `java.time` api.